# How to access pfsense's LAN without vpn?

Tags: networking, pfsense

I have the following setup and want to access both server A and server B by their IPs from the workstation without VPN and without port-forwarding.

[image: Diagram]

What I have tried so far is:

- In pfsense_1, I added 192.168.1.46 as a gateway (this is the WAN IP of pfsense_2).
- In pfsense_1, I added a static route for 10.0.0.0/8 to the gateway of 192.168.1.46.
- In pfsense_1, I added a rule on LAN interface to allow access from (source) network - 192.168.1.0/24 to (destination) network 10.0.0.0/8.
- In pfsense_2, I added a floating rule to allow any <-> any for both interfaces WAN and LAN.

Am I missing anything here? NAT is enabled in automatic mode in both pfsense servers.

Comment: A common misconception for hobbyists is that a router MUST also perform NAT in addition to routing and  firewalling to provide security and network segregation. That is not the case. You can achieve that also without NAT. Since you have don't have overlapping IP-ranges and you have control over all three routers in your internal network, disable all internal NAT and after creating normal routing rules that should allow each machine to reach all other directly, pending firewall rules of course. You only need to NAT IPv4 traffic to and from the public internet.

Comment: https://superuser.com/a/1707585/554702 I don't remember if I had actually confirmed that NAT in xSense is *stateless* though. If it's really *stateful* like NAT in Linux, you don't have to disable it to get the problem solved, even though it is true that the second / third layer NAT is unnecessary (assuming the first layer one covers all the inner subnets). The bottom line is, make sure you notice the setting option shown in the last screenshot in the answer.

Answer (score 2):

- On pfsense1, add a static route to 10.0.0.0/8 via 192.168.1.46.
- On pfsense1, use the WAN router ("modem") as default gateway.
- On pfsense2 and workstation, use 192.168.1.1 as default route (0.0.0.0/0).
- Make sure you add rules on both firewalls permitting the desired traffic.
- **Don't use NAT** except on the "modem" router. NAT is only required between different address domain (usually public vs private) but needs to be avoided otherwise because it breaks IP's end-to-end principle.

Conceptionally, you might want to consider using a single firewall (or HA cluster) between your LAN switches and the WAN router. Creating VLANs on the switches and trunking them to the single pfSense is more flexible and less maintenance.